# To which programming language should I switch my project?

Tags: programming-languages

I have a large program written with my own patched version of the GNU Eiffel (SmallEiffel) compiler. While I love the language I'm running into the problem that the compiler is O(n^2) or worse on the compiled system size. So I have to move soon.

ISE Eiffel the only alive Eiffel compiler is not an option for various reasons. Mostly because the compiled code runs way to slow.

I'm looking for a language which is:

1. imperative and OO
2. has generics/templates
3. compiles to native code and does not
   require .NET/Java
4. statically typed (which means fast)
5. garbage collected
6. cross platform
7. not as ugly and braindead as C++

I couldn't come up with anything else then D but this looks a little bit to low level and non stable. Is there really none which satisfies this seven points?

Comment: Hmm you rebel against Java and C++ - could be making your life difficult, especially if you want native code, and statically typed. I'd be hesitant to think this was anything but a plug for the new Google language. C++ can be much simpler if you use it cleanly and consistently. The use of smart pointers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) may be worth investigating in C++ as an alternative to garbage collection.

Comment: Maybe I'm stepping on a landmine, but how is C++ braindead?

Comment: Sorry MPelletier, i don't bite there are enough answers out there why C++ is the worst and most complex.

Comment: Look a little more closely at D.  It has low level constructs like pointers and inline assembler, but take a look at std.range or std.algorithm, for example, in D2.  You can program at a very high level in D.  You are right that D is not very stable yet, but that's a short term problem.  D2 should stabilize in the next 6 months or so.  Therefore, if this is a large/long-term project, you may want to reconsider D.

Comment: The problem is that this was exactly what people told me about SmallEiffel years ago, and this was exactly what people told me about my GUI library (FOX) years ago. I'm still waiting on both for the next  6 month. So i learned one thing the hard way: Never judge a project by anthing else then the current state of it. And this is currently a NO for D.

Comment: Ok, but D is a special case because a huge push is being made to stabilize it ahead of Andrei Alexandrescu's book, "The D Programming Language", which is coming out next March.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling 'object oriented native code compiler' brings up Objective Caml before Eiffel.

If you're willing to take your chances on a research compiler, check out the [Diesel language](http://wasp.cs.washington.edu/wasp_diesel.html) and the native-code Vortex compiler (written for Diesel in Diesel).  It is a research project, but it is stable, and Craig Chambers is one of the best people in the business.

Answer (score 4):

OCaml, perhaps?

Comment: A surprising answer, but then OCaml is a surprisingly imperative functional language.  Worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

You could write in Java and compile to native-ish code with GCJ (it will be native code, but you'll need to link against a fair portion of code that makes up all the things Java needs at run-time. Your users will not need to install a JRE.)

Answer (score 0):

What about Python?
It is OO, scripted language, runs fast, has generic templates.